# Bootup Problem Ubuntu Core

Tags: pi-3, boot, boot-issues, ubuntu

I have two raspberry pi 3's that boot perfectly with raspian, but don't boot with ubuntu snappy core.

Here's what I did:

```
$ wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-snappy/16.04/current/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz
$ sha256sum ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz 
 -> correct checksum
$ xz -d ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz 
$ dd if=ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img of=/dev/sdb
```

Everything seemed to work at this point. When I tried to boot the pi with the sdcard here's what happened:

- Red led turned on,
- green led blinking,
- Some messages on screen, that the pi is booting up (I could take a photo if you want to see them).

After that, the display just shows 4 raspberries. The green led is still blinking, usb mouse + keyboard have power, both lan status led's light up.

I would be thankful if anyone knows why the pi isn't booting or how to fix the problem.

I want to use the raspy to run a nextcloud cloudserver. (I think ubuntu is better than raspbian: Nextcloud is probably well testet on ubuntu, and security updates are afaik faster. Ubuntu mate worked, but the nextcloud snap package had some troubles with ubuntu mate)

Answer (score 1):

You might try running sync after writing the image to the card.  I couldn't get snappy to boot past a mount error until I did that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these instructions: https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/installation-medias.

1. Download the image
2. Plug in and unmount sd card
3. Extract and install to sd card using `xzcat <image file .xz> | sudo dd of=<drive address> bs=32M`

Comment: I tried it. This does not fix the problem

Comment: If you want to use ubuntu, you could try downloading `xubuntu` or `lubuntu` from [here](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/)

Comment: Kernel panic on 2 seperate devices with 2 seperate sd cards:
not syncinc: VFS: Unable to mount root fson unknown-block (179,2)
Lubuntu sha256sum: 12464124ddb2e9a11cd5d75066c788054773a558c5f4cdb182cd545e32de33b5  lubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz

Comment: What type of sd card are you using?

Comment: SanDisk Ultra 32GB micro sd HC I (10)

Comment: and a Paradies 16GB micro sd HC I Class (10)